# Semicontinuity of this function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> We get a continuous function $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$, and we defined: 
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases} g(x) & \text{ if $x\in[a,b]$} \\0  & \text{ if $x\not\in [a,b]$} \end{cases}$$
>   Prove that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and $\int_{\Bbb R}f=\int_a^b g$.

I think that $f$ is semicontinuous, however I'm having some troubles while proving so. I considered cases:

- if $g(a)=g(b)=0$,
- if $g(a)=0$ but $g(b)\not=0$,
- if $g(b)=0$ but $g(a)\not=0$,
- if $g(a)<0<g(b)$,
- if $g(b)<0<g(a)$,
- if $0<g(a)<g(b)$,
- if $0<g(b)<g(a)$,
- if $g(a)<g(b)<0$,
- if $g(b)<g(a)<0$,

I'm having troubles with the cases $g(a)<0<g(b)$. I keep thinking in these two particular examples: 
$$h_1(x)=\begin{cases} x & x\in[-1,1] \\ 0 & x\not\in[-1,1] \end{cases}, h_2(x)=\begin{cases} \tan x & x\in[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}] \\ 0 & x\not\in[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\end{cases}$$
I get confused to see whether they're semicontinuous, in $h_1$ we get $h_1(a)=-1<0<1=h_1(b)$, but in $h_2$ $h_2(a)=-\infty<0<\infty=h_2(b)$. What do I do? Are these functions really semicontinous?

Comment: the semicontinuity of $f$ depends on weather $g$ is positive or negative at the boundaries. you might try an approach like this: $f=f_{+}-f_{-}$ with $f_{+}=\max\left\{f,0\right\}$ and $f_{-}=\max\left\{-f,0\right\}$

Comment: and then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{+}-\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{-}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ have opposite sign, then $f$ is not globally semicontinuous. If $g(a) < 0 < g(b)$, then $f$ is

- lower semicontinuous in $a$, and
- upper semicontinuous in $b$,

but not continuous in either point, hence $f$ isn't globally semicontinuous.

If $a < c < b$, then $f$ is however semicontinuous on the two intervals $(-\infty,c]$ and $[c,+\infty)$. That suffices to show that it is integrable.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still wondering why even if $f$ is not globally semicontinuous the function is integrable? I mean I can see it but not in formal terms

Comment: Semicontinuity is a very strong condition. Integrability has much lesser demands of regularity. In this case, you can for example write $f$ as the difference of two bounded semicontinuous functions, using $g(x)+K$ and $K$ to construct $f_1,f_2$ and write $f(x) = f_1(x) - f_2(x)$. Or you can choose sequences of simple functions converging to $f$ that are $0$ outside $[a,b]$, there are many options to show the integrability, which one is most convenient depends on which definition of the integral one uses (there are many equivalent but different ways to define it).

Comment: I thought the semicontinuity was an easier way to prove this, my original approach was using sequences that converged to $g$, but I had too many problems with the definitions outside of $[a,b]$ that's when it hit me that maybe it was easier with semicont. Btw, what do you mean by $g(x)+K$ and $K$?

Comment: Choose $K > 0$ so that $g(x)+K \geqslant 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Then $$f_1(x) = \begin{cases}g(x)+K &, x\in[a,b]\\0 &,x\notin[a,b]\end{cases}$$ is upper semicontinuous, as is $f_2(x) = \begin{cases}K&, x\in[a,b]\\0&, x\notin[a,b].\end{cases}$ So $f_1$ and $f_2$ are integrable by semicontinuity, and $f = f_1-f_2$ is integrable by linearity.